# ObjC Conditional compilation in Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to have a method behave differently between iOS and MacOS. I need this to process keyboard events on the MacOS platform.

Browsing the source code, I found the following macros in use. When running my code for the macos platform, I only get "begin" being output to console, as if the "_CC_PLATFORM_MAC" wasn't defined.

Am I doing this wrong?

```
-(void)processEvent:(NSEvent*)event{

    NSLog(@"begin");


#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

    NSLog(@"nothing here");

#elif defined(__CC_PLATFORM_MAC)

    NSLog(@"process keyboard event");


#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_MAC

}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Ok, just found out... forgot to #import "cocos2d.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header was missing #import "cocos2d.h"